# Merge fields from different arrays in jq

Tags: json, api, jq

I have the following kind of array:

```
{
  "name": [
    "Paul",
    "Alex",
    "John"
  ],
  "age": [
    "22",
    "31",
    "56"
  ],
  "town": [
    "New York",
    "Los Angeles",
    "Detroit"
  ]
}
```

From this I want to create new arrays with the relevant information combined into one large array called "items".

```
{"items": [
    {
        "name": "Paul",
        "age": "22",
        "town": "New York"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": "31",
        "town": "Los Angeles"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "56",
        "town": "Detroit"
    },
]}
```

I found out that I can do something like this to get the first string in an array but I can't find how to iterate over all strings.

```
jq '{items: [{ name: .name | first,  age: .age | first, town: .town | first}]}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution, which would be easy to adapt to handle the renaming of keys:

```
[.[]]
| transpose
| {items: map( {name: .[0], age: .[1], town: .[2] } )}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I am going with this one as I indeed need to rename the keys (which I forgot to mention).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that makes it easy to handle the key names without explicitly mentioning any of them:

```
def objectify($keys):
  with_entries( .key |= $keys[.] );

keys_unsorted as $keys
| [.[]]
| transpose
| {items: map( objectify($keys) )}
```